# Python: raise inside of try block, for breaking out of it

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a function that needs to execute one of two blocks of code:

- code A
- code B

it needs to execute code B if some variable `check` is False, or if code A fails. Either code A or B must be executed, not both. The way I wrote this is:

```
try:
    if check:
        raise TypedError('')
    # code A
except TypedError:
    # code B
```

I feel bad for this for two reasons:

- TypedError is the class of errors I expect from code A, but it has nothing to do with my code, in fact, is specific of some package I'm using.
- If `check` is True and an error occurs in code B, it appears from traceback that it occurred while handling another error, which is untrue and potentially confusing.

Do you think there is a more pythonic way of writing this same program?

Comment: Whether it's Pythonic or not is hard to say.  Python uses `StopIteration` as an exception to exit a loop, and what you're doing isn't much different.  Is there a reason you're not just using `if:  .... else: ....` ?

Comment: Exceptions are usually used when the condition should be handled in the caller of the function that detects it. If you're raising the exception in the same function with `try/except`, it's usually a wrong design, you should just use an ordinary conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nice and useful comment from @FrankYellin made me realise there is a better solution I couldn't think about before:

```
if check:
    try:
        # code A
    except TypedError:
        check = False
if not check:
    # code B
```

I think this is better, and only one line longer. Thank you for bearing my silly question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reafactoring your code to something like this:

```py
def run_code_a():
    try:
       # code A 
       # ... 
       return True
    except TypedError:
       return False


if not check or not run_code_a():
    run_code_b()
```

Here Code B will run either if `check` is `False` or Code A throws the `TypedError` exception. Either Code A or Code B will be executed.